# PHP, Why doesn't anyone use the ?: operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I cant seem to find any discussion about this.

In JavaScript to check if something exists, and use a default if it doesn't is like this:

```
var myvariable = mysetting || 3
```

In PHP from what I understand, the same thing can be done like this:

```
$myvariable = $mysetting ?: 3;
```

Am i completely off on this? I understand the implications of not using `isset()` and `not_empty()` and all that, but if I just want to know if the variable exists and is truthy otherwise use a default - this should work I think. Does this syntax have any hidden bad things about it?

Comment: `var myvariable = mysetting || 3` is a dirty trick if you want my opinion.

Comment: The ternary operator's been in PHP for a long while, but the shortcut `?:` has only been available since 5.4 or something.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this is what that page says: Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Comment: That's true, it is possible to leave out the middle part. That's why I agree with @Sebas - it's a dirty trick and possibly why you do not see it used more.

Comment: What do you guys mean by it's a dirty trick? I would like to be not dirty, but having notices suppressed, it seems like that is a much cleaner approach than having if isset() and not_empty() all over the place. I just learned about it, and am trying to decide if I should start using, and am open to any real reasons why not to use it

Comment: Suppressing notices is the top of a very slippery slope. You should always code so that there are no errors and do nothing to intentionally hide those errors. As your application becomes more complex, your OS changes, PHP is modified, etc. these suppressions could become a mask for potentially worse problems and troubleshooting becomes exponentially more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't work. That code will still throw a notice `Notice: Undefined variable: mysetting in C:\wamp\www\x.php on line`, which might be visible to the user, depending on the PHP settings. Apart from that, it will work. If notices are suppressed, then the end result is correct.

So, to get around that, you can either use `isset`, which isn't really a function, but a language construct, and is specifically designed to do this check:

```
$myvariable = isset($mysetting)? $mysetting: 3;
```

Or you can suppress the notice using the `@` operator:

```
$myvariable = @$mysetting ?: 3;
```

For this specific case, maybe it's acceptable, but in general the use of `@` is frowned upon by many. Personally, I would rather use a couple more characters and make it feel less 'dirty', but it's a matter of opinion.

Another reason why people may not use it, is that it's relatively new (PHP 5.3). Not everyone might know of this new syntax or be comfortable with it. They have been used to `isset` for years, and old habits die hard.

Comment: `$myvariable = @$mysetting ?: 3;`

Comment: You're only suppressing the notice @DávidHorváth, and that is really a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Those statements are not equivalent. From what I have found the javascript is equivalent to:

```
if (!mysetting) {
  myvariable = 3;
} else {
  myvariable = mysetting;
}
```

Whereas the equivalent PHP statement using the ternary operator would be:

```
$mysetting = isset($myvariable) ? $myvariable : 3;
```

aka:

```
if( isset($myvariable) ) {
  $mysetting = $myvariable;
} else {
  $mysetting = 3;
}
```

The ternary operator is essentially a shorthand for and if/else statement, and the first operand is interpreted as a logical expression.